# Is there object importance in LightGMB?

Tags: python-3.x, lightgbm, catboost

I know that in **CatBoost** in Python API there is a possibility to calculate **object importance** (don't confuse it with feature importance) with *get_object_importance* method.

I would like to know is there a similar option in **LightGMB**?